# Remove all commas from a string in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have many classes and want to remove the commas in them if any commas exist there.

I wrote the below code but the code does not work correctly. The second class value is replaced with the first value.

```js
   
var removebox = $(".remove"),
removeboxHtml = removebox.html();
removebox.html(removeboxHtml.replace(/,/g , ''));
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <span class="remove">,17500000</span>
    <span class="remove">,2479000</span>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `but the code does not work correctly` - what exactly is the problem, saying `it doesn't work` doesn't cut it

Comment: I ran the snippet you provided, and it ran correctly.

Comment: @trincot yeah it work but the second class value replace with the first value

Comment: @inaz, so why did you not mention this in the question? Seems essential information.

Comment: @trincot - he did say :"the code does not work correctly" - that should be enough :p

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this. Updated your code:

```js
   

$(".remove").each(function(){
   
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/,/g , ''));
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<span class="remove">,17500000</span>
<span class="remove">,2479000</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please make `removeboxHtml` a local var and don't pollute the global namespace.

Comment: removed the `removeboxHtml` variable

Comment: @AlivetoDie Glad to help.

Answer (score 3):

I would iterate over each element and change its' text:

```
var removebox = $(".remove");

removebox.each(function () {

  var oldtext = $(this).text();

  $(this).text(oldtext.replace(',', ''));

});
```

Answer (score 1):

While you've already accepted an answer to this problem it's worth pointing out that they're both rather too verbose, and one answer, [shennan's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39685904/82548) (at the time of writing), will only remove one comma from each of the given elements should multiple commas be present therein.

That said, a more concise version is below:

```
// select the elements to update:
$('.remove')

  // we then use the text method's anonymous function,
  // using the two arguments:
  // index: the index of the current element in the collection,
  // currentText: the text of the current element of the
  // collection over the text method iterates:
  .text(function(index, currentText) {

    // here we access the currentText variable and use
    // String.prototype.replace(), with a regular literal (/.../)
    // to remove all occurrences (g) of the specified comma character
    // replacing those occurrences with an empty string (''); this
    // is comma-removed string is returned to the text method in
    // order to update the text of each element as required:
    return currentText.replace(/,/g, '');
});
```

```js
$('.remove').text(function(index, currentText) {
  return currentText.replace(/,/g, '');
});
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<span class="remove">,17500000</span>
<span class="remove">,2479000</span>
<span class="remove">5,279,000</span>
```

Of course it's also worth showing that the above is perfectly possible in plain JavaScript, and still relatively concise:

```
// we use document.querySelectorAll() to retrieve
// a non-live HTMLCollection of elements matched
// by the supplied CSS selector:
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.remove');

// we use Array.from() to convert an Array-like Object
// into an Array, in order that we can then iterate
// over those elements using Array.prototype.forEach():
Array.from(elements).forEach(function(elem) {
  // 'elem', the first argument, is a reference to the
  // current element of the Array of elements over
  // which we're iterating.

  // here we retrieve the current text-content of the
  // current element, and use String.prototype.replace(),
  // with a regular expression (exactly as above) to
  // replace all occurrences ('g') of the comma character
  // (',') in the string supplied by elem.textContent and
  // we replace those commas with a empty string (''):
  elem.textContent = elem.textContent.replace(/,/g, '');
});
```

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.remove');

Array.from(elements).forEach(function(elem) {
  elem.textContent = elem.textContent.replace(/,/g, '');
});
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<span class="remove">,17500000</span>
<span class="remove">,2479000</span>
<span class="remove">5,279,000</span>
```

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).
  - [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
  - [`Document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
  - "[Guide to JavaScript Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)."
  - [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).
- jQuery:

  - [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).